# Forwarding tcpdump packets on remote gateway to wireshark

Tags: networking, remote-access, wireshark

I'm trying to capture packets on a usb over ethernet interface (usb0) on a gateway. I have a ionoPi that is connected to the gateway (i.e. no gui on the pi and gateway) that sits between my ubuntu vm (subnet 254) and the gateway (subnet 90). The ionoPi contains and runs all the tests for the gateway we are developing and I'd like to see ethernet traffic on the usb0 interface on the gateway to troubleshoot some of these tests.

The only solution I've been able to come up with to attempt to achieve this is do the following shown in the [Wireshark remote capture via remote forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MImum.png) image.

Note that I have an ssh-key set up for my remote forward as shown in the left-side of the terminal. I know this solution does not work as when I listen on the usb0 interface on the gateway with tcpdump, I see a bunch of packets (note left-side of terminal). On Wireshark I don't see this traffic.

Where am I going wrong? Is this set up possible?

Some additional material:

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wBMz.png)

Stack Overflow reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/362529/how-can-i-sniff-the-traffic-of-remote-machine-with-wireshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I listen on the usb0 interface on the gateway with tcpdump, I see a bunch of packets (note left-side of terminal). On Wireshark I don't see this traffic.

Every one of the packets shown on the *left* are sent from or to port 22 (shown as port "ssh"). But the tcpdump capture on the *right* was given filter `not port 22`, so of course those packets will get filtered out.

Comment: That appears to have resolved the issue; thanks. I did not notice that.

I'll now run my tests and hopefully this allow me to troubleshoot ethernet traffic on the gateway using wireshark.